# Google Chrome does not render page after losing focus in AwesomeWM

Tags: nvidia, awesome-wm

I have installed fresh Arch Linux with `linux-ck` and `awesomewm`. After that I have installed `google-chrome` and started it. Everything works well, but if I open other application (chrome lose focus) and then got back to the chrome, it freezes. Mouse cursor works as expected (cursor changes after hovering link, input field, etc) but view is not updated.
Everything works well again if I change desktop to the second and go back to the first again (mod+2, mod+1). Chrome works, responses etc well.

I bet this issue has something in common with hardware acceleration. If I run some game (steam), lose focus, get back to the game - it shows last rendered screen before focus has been lost (sound is ok, game is responsible but does not update screen).

I use nvidia. Do I need some extra configuration to handle it ?

Comment: 2020, this problem still exists on WIndows. I have to open Start menu to gain render back :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was `xcompmgr` which caused "freezing" view. I switched it to `unagi` and all of the problems have gone.

Comment: Could you comment on this? The current answer makes to me no sense without more context.

Comment: @Benedictus To provide transparency, etc I was using `xcompmgr` which didn't work properly in my configuration. I was running it manually during the X start. Switching manager to `unagi` solved the problem then. I cannot say anything more right now because it was 1,5 year ago but there were no rocket science about that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Chrome settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling hardware acceleration as Alex pointed out solved the issue. This bug has been brought forward before in [awesome's issues GitHub page](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/179).

Apparently, the problem is not awesome. Graphics drivers might be involved but the main suspect seems to be the compositing manager. Running awesome with the "--no-argb" flag and disabling the comp manager seems to solve the problem.